# char array to object array

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to convert or typecast a char array "gg[16][16]" to an object array "ff[16][16]"?

charToObject() and toObject() are both mostly used for single values.

Should this simply work:

```
Object[][] ff = (Object [][])(gg [16][16]);
```

Comment: `Should this simply work` - have you tried it? What was the result?

Comment: Presumably `gg[16][16]` is a single char, not an array. Did you mean `(Object[][]) gg`?

Comment: gg[16][16] is a 2D char array.

Comment: I believe what Mr Skeet was hinting at was that `gg` is an array; `gg[16][16]` refers to an individual element in the `gg` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a 2d array you need a nested for loop that look something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<gg.length; i++)
  for(int j=0; j<gg[i].length; j++)
    gg[i][j]=ff[i][j];
```

assuming that gg is your original array, and ff is the new one. This will start by checking all "rows" in the first "column" of the array and assign that to the proper part of the new array, then continue looping thru the second "column" and assigning all "rows" that belongs to that column etc.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot cast arrays. You need to iterate over the array (two loops for two dimensions) and assign new values

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't cast arrays with primitive types in them to Object[] arrays. You could use Character[][] instead, then you wouldn't even need to cast it to Object[][].